# Ajax post a PHP page inside php exec() page

Tags: php, ajax, exec

I am trying to ajax post a php page inside a PHP page which is being executed suing PHP `exec()` command.

This is the code being used for calling the page

```
exec ("C:/AppServ/php5/php.exe -f C:/AppServ/www/site/test.php varibale1 varibale2 , $output, $return");
```

The page is being called, and if I put some code to insert into DB it works but when I put Ajax call that is not working.

I am calling the third page as

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test3.php',
     data: fd,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
    }
});
```

My question, is Ajax call will work inside this page or not and if yes then how ?

Comment: No, that won't work. Any JavaScript in that file will not run, since you need a browser to run it. Also, the AJAX operation is looking to create an HTTP connection with a web server, but you are running from the console.

Comment: If you would outline what you are actually wanting to achieve, someone may be able to advise you.